# Complete caching disable in Chromium

Tags: chrome, cache

There are plenty approaches of cache disable in chrome, but the only one for Chromium I've found is not quite fits my needs.

[Suggested](http://himanen.info/disable-chromium-browser-disk-cache/) :

Edit `chromium` config somewhere in `/etc` to set

`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1"`

But didn't work for me, because

1. There is nothing to configure in `/etc` for chromium
2. I want to disable as many disk writes as possible by [policies](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start) but not the command line

So, my question is, what should I write in chromium policy to redirect as much writes as possible to RAM?

Answer (score 5):

File is

```
/etc/chromium-browser/default

cat /etc/chromium-browser/default

Default settings for chromium-browser. 
This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Options to pass to chromium-browser

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, if you don't want to change the cache setting permanently, you can also run chromium temporarily with a modified environment. For instance, using bash:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1" chromium
```